# Serialize FHIR Bundle into a JSON

Tags: c#, serialization, hl7-fhir

I need to serialize a FHIR Bundle (ImagingStudy/Patient) into a JSON String, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer: Using the Hl7.Fhir library, which has serialization methods.

It would be helpful if you added what you have already tried and what problems you ran into.

(edited to reflect c# tag)